# max_value and min_value for each column in scikit IterativeImputer

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, imputation

I have this data set with 78 columns and 5707 rows. Almost every column has missing values and I would like to impute them with IterativeImputer. If I understood it correctly, it will make a "smarter" imputation on each column based on the information from other columns.

However, when imputing, I do not want the imputed values to be less than the observed minimum or more than the observed maximum. I realize there are `max_value` and `min_value` parameters, but I do not want to impose a "global" limit to the imputations, instead, I want each column to have its own `max_value` and `min_value` (which is the already observed maximum and minimum values). Because otherwise, the values in the columns do not make sense (negative values for headcounts, negative values for rates, etc.)

Is there a way to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to set max and min different for each column then you can go in a loop and in each iteration select the column using `sklearn.compose.make_column_selector` or `sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer` and then apply iterative imputer to that column giving max and min of that column as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To help future developers, maybe I can help

You can set a list of minimum and maximum values for each feature like this:

```
    # restrict the values to be predicted to a min / max range
    minimum_before = list(df.iloc[:, :].min(axis=0))
    maximum_after = list(df.iloc[:, :].max(axis=0))
```

And then reference them when calling the imputed

```
    # impute missing values
    imputer = IterativeImputer(random_state=random_state,
                               imputation_order='descending',
                               n_nearest_features=None,
                               initial_strategy='mean',
                               max_iter=30,
                               min_value=minimum_before,
                               max_value=maximum_after,
                               skip_complete=True,
                               tol=0.001, 
                               verbose=1)

df[:] = imputer.fit_transform(df)
```